# Merging columns if another column has a count > 1

Tags: mysql, sql

When matching to column_1, I'm trying to create a column that is merged column if the count of column_1 is greater than 1, and just the value of one of the columns if 1.  So far I can get the column to merge properly, but it only returns the first row back, not all of them.

Example Table

```
id, col_1,   col_2,   col_3
---------------------------
1, 'Name1', 'Value',  '1',
2, 'Name2', 'Value',  '2',
3, 'Name2', 'Value',  '3',
4, 'Name3', 'Value2', '1',
5, 'Name2', 'Value3', '1';
```

What I would like back

```
2, Name2, Value 2
3, Name2, Value 3
5, Name2, Value3
```

What I've attempted so far

```
SELECT id,
IF (count(col_2) > 1, concat(col_2, ' ', col_3), col_2) as merge
FROM mytable 
where col_1 = 'Name2'
```

which only returns '2, Value 2' Thanks for the help. I've messed with it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ce7e/7

Comment: I think you're after `select col_1, sum(col_3) from my_table group by col_1`?

Comment: Your query is correct, are you sure you have 3 rows with `col_1` as 'Name2'?

Comment: @Starx, Yep. I shorted up my data and have been messing with it at the sqlfiddle link I edited into the OP.

Comment: Do you want to return anything if col_1 only has a count of 1? (From your list of what you want back, it looks like you want to completely exclude such results.)

Comment: @MarkBannister I want just col_2 if the count is 1, and col_2+col_3 if the count is greater then 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select t.id, t.col_1,
IF (t2.cnt > 1, concat(t.col_2, ' ', t.col_3), t.col_2) as merge
from mytable t
inner join 
(
  SELECT col_1, col_2, count(*) as cnt
  From myTable
  where col_1 = 'Name2'
  group by col_1, col_2
) t2 on t2.col_1 = t.col_1 and t2.col_2 = t.col_2
```

Output

```
ID  COL_1   MERGE
2   Name2   Value 2
3   Name2   Value 3
5   Name2   Value3
```

This worked when I was playing on the fiddle link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`count()` is a aggregate function, thus it return single row as output.

You can user the following query to make sure `col_2` has some value before concatenating

```
SELECT id,
IF (col_2 <> "" , concat(col_2, ' ', col_3), col_2) as merge
FROM mytable 
where col_1 = 'Name2'
```